# How to preview a Source Assistant SQL Command with parameters

Tags: ssis

TL;DR: A data flow task "works" when the package runs, but I am unable to view the query when clicking "preview" in the Data flow Source Assistant.

My working theory is that somehow the Source Assistant is unable to get the value of the parameter when previewing. I tried to resolve this problem by use of (iterations) "Parameter" and "Variable" without success. The example shown below use "Parameter".

In an SSIS Data Flow task, I have a Source Assistant with "SQL Command" as its data access mode.

```
SELECT h.Campus,
    h.StudentName,
    h.StudentId,
    h.EntryDate
FROM dbo.RwsBaseEnrollmentHistory h
WHERE h.Campus = ?;
```

The question mark indicates a parameter, which I have defined in "Parameters".

[image: Parameter is defined here]

In the OLE DB Source Editor, I made sure to map the variable to the parameter.

[image: The parameter is mapped to the variable here.]

When I click "Preview" I get an error:

[image: Error displaying preview]

The data in question cannot be shared, but trust me when I say that when I run the package, the query works as intended. It's the inability to preview the query that I'd like to be able to fix.

What do I need to do so that I can preview the query without having to hard-code the parameter value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled into a possible answer. It appears to work so far and I haven't been able to break it. If there is a better way of doing this I would love feedback.

This is my resolution:

1. Create a variable to hold the desired query (like shown in the example above). In this example, I name it `EnrollmentHistory`.

[image: Create a new variable to hold the query.]

2. In the "Expression", click the [...] button and paste the query. Be sure that double-quotes surround the query.

> ```
> "SELECT 
>    h.Campus,  
>    h.StudentName,
>    h.StudentId,
>    h.EntryDate 
>   FROM dbo.RwsBaseEnrollmentHistory h 
>   WHERE h.Campus = '" + @ [User::Campus] + "'"
> ```

Press the "Evaluate Expression" button and press OK.

3. Go back to your Source Assistant and select "SQL Command from Variable" as the Data Access Mode and the Variable you just defined (in this case `EnrollmentHistory`) as the Variable name. You will see that the parameter is correctly resolved in the Variable Value.

[image]